# Firestore Map field performance with large dataset

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of products, each user can buy multiple tickets for a product. When I fetch a product I need to know how many tickets a user has bought per product. I currently have product as a separate collection and I fetch a list of tickets per products for the current logged in user. This worked great but I was using an `in` statement to make a single query to fetch the tickets in a single query for multiple products, and Firestore only allows 10 items in an `in` statement

I'm considering storing the count of tickets on each product as a map. How does this affect the performance of the snapshotListener? Let's say I listen to 100 products and each has a Map with 100k key-values where the key is a string and the value is an Int.

Is it easy to update the map, can i do an increment on the value of a specific field?

Security is not an issue, it's ok to have the ticket count for all users public

```
Product {
    name: String
    ....
    tickets: {
       "USERID": 5,
       // 100k more records
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and narrow it down to a single question?  I read three questions here, which is rather broad.  In general, the contents of a document do not affect performance of anything other than the time it takes to download that document to the client.

Comment: Well I do have multiple questions related to this data structure change :)

Comment: I'll remind you that that multiple questions per post is off topic for Stack Overflow.  One of your questions is asking for offsite links, which is also off topic.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm considering storing the count of tickets on each product as a map. How does this affect the performance of the snapshotListener?

It has no effect on the performance of anything other than the time it takes to download the document.

> Is it easy to update the map, can i do an increment on the value of a specific field?

Yes, it's easy.  Use dot notation to locate the field to increment, and use FieldValue.increment() to increment it.

Comment: thanks, sorry another question but related, since increment is atomic does it mean multiple users can update the map safely?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "safely".  Since you've already identified it as atomic, that gives you all the guarantees that you would normally expect from an atomic update.  There is no "catch" here.